Evaluating $\int \sin^2 (2\theta) d\theta$ went Wrong
I tried evaluating the integral $\int \sin^2 (2\theta) d\theta$ which looks like:

I tried first to use Integration by Parts, then Integration by Substitution, and then Tabular Integration by Parts.
I want to know what possibly went wrong here:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int(\sin 2 \theta)^2 d \theta \\
& =\int(2 \sin \theta \cos \theta)^2 d \theta \quad u=\sin ^2 \theta \quad d v=\cos ^2 \theta \\
& =\int 4 \sin ^2 \theta \cos ^2 \theta d \theta \quad d u=2 \sin \theta \cos \theta, v=\frac{1}{2}\left(\theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}\right) \\
& =4 \int \sin ^2 \theta \cos ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =4\left[\sin ^2 \theta\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}\right)\right)-\int \frac{1}{2}\left(\theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}\right) \sin 2 \theta d \theta\right] \\
& =4\left[\sin ^2 \theta\left(\frac{1}{2} \theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{4}\right)-\int \frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}\left(\theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}\right) d \theta\right] \\
\end{aligned}
$$
From here, I continue with using Integration by Substitution and further using Tabular Integration by Parts:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text { Let } u=2 \theta \Rightarrow \frac{d u}{d \theta}=2, d \theta=\frac{d u}{2} \\
& =\int \frac{\sin u}{2}\left(\frac{u}{2}+\frac{\sin u}{2}\right) \frac{d u}{2} \\
& =\int \frac{\sin u}{4}\left(\frac{u+\sin u}{2}\right) d u \\
& =\int \frac{u \sin u+\sin ^2 u}{8} d u \\
& =\frac{1}{8} \int u \sin u+\sin ^2 u d u \\
& =\frac{1}{8}\left[(-u \cos u+\sin u)+\frac{1}{2}\left(u-\frac{\sin 2 u}{2}\right)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
Compiling all these working:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& = 4 \left[ \sin^2 \theta \left( \frac{1}{2} \theta + \frac{\sin 2 \theta}{4} \right) - \frac{1}{8} \left( -2 \theta \cos 2 \theta + \sin 2 \theta - \frac{1}{2} \left( 2 \theta - \frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2} \right) \right) \right] + c \\
& =4\left[\sin ^2 \theta\left(\frac{1}{2} \theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{8}\left[-2 \theta \cos 2 \theta+\sin 2 \theta+\theta-\frac{\sin 4 \theta}{4}\right)\right]+c \\
& =4\left[\sin ^2 \theta\left(\frac{1}{2} \theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{4}\right)+4 \theta \cos 2 \theta-\frac{1}{8} \sin 2 \theta+\frac{\sin 4 \theta}{32}\right]+c \\
& =4 \sin ^2 \theta\left(\frac{1}{2} \theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{4}\right)+16 \theta \cos 2 \theta-\frac{1}{2} \sin 2 \theta+\frac{\sin 4 \theta}{8}+c \\
& =2 \theta \sin ^2 \theta+\sin ^2 \theta \sin 2 \theta+16 \theta \cos 2 \theta-\frac{1}{2} \sin 2 \theta+\frac{\sin 4 \theta}{8}+c
\end{aligned}
$$
The working was wrong as compared from WolframAlpha, I wish to know where did I went wrong?

Did you check if the two antiderivatives differ by a constant?

@SineoftheTime WA Result and my check

You should use the half-angle identity $\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \frac{1 - \cos x}{2}$ which in your case gives $\sin^2(2\theta) = \frac{1 - \cos(4\theta)}{2}$. This is then easy to integrate.

Your procedure is rather illogical, since after substituting $u=2\theta$ you computed $\int \sin^2 u \,du$, which is your original integral. Your method is correct, but you've made an error, in fact:
\begin{align}
I&=4\left(\sin ^2 \theta\left(\frac{1}{2} \theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{4}\right)-\int \frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}\left(\theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}\right) d \theta\right) \\
&=2\theta \sin^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta \sin 2\theta -\frac 48 \left(-2\theta \cos 2\theta +\sin 2\theta +\frac{1}{2}\left(2\theta -\frac{\sin 4\theta }{2}\right)\right)\\&= 2\theta \sin^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta \sin 2\theta +\theta \cos 2 \theta-\frac 12 \sin 2\theta-\frac 12 \theta+\frac 18 \sin 4 \theta 
\end{align}
The antiderivative provided by wolfram is $\frac 12 \theta-\frac 18 \sin 4 \theta$; if you subtract the two antiderivatives you get:
\begin{align}
&2\theta \sin^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta \sin 2\theta +\theta \cos 2 \theta-\frac 12 \sin 2\theta- \theta+\frac 14 \sin 4 \theta  \\=& 2\theta \sin^2\theta+2\sin^3 \theta \cos \theta +\theta(1-2\sin^2 \theta)-\frac 12\sin 2 \theta -\theta +\cos^3 \theta \sin \theta-\sin^3 \theta \cos \theta\\=&\sin^3 \theta \cos \theta-\sin \theta \cos \theta+\cos^3 \theta \sin \theta\\=&(1-\cos^2 \theta)\sin \theta \cos \theta-\sin \theta \cos \theta+\cos^3 \theta \sin\theta=0
\end{align}

I felt this answer was not what I am looking for, because your final expression does not match mine, and the u-substitution was for:
$$\int \frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2} \big(\theta+\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}\big) d \theta$$
so I later changed my mind as I never performed the calculation $$\int \sin^2 u du$$

@moonbag1212 Ok, no worries. Your last expression is different from mine because you've made an error. Note that in the last line before "Compiling all these working:" you computed the antiderivative of $u \sin u +\sin^2 u$ where $u=2\theta$, i.e. you computed the antiderivative of $2\theta\sin 2\theta \color{red}+\sin^2 2\theta$
